# Getting undefined for my environment variables

Tags: node.js, angular

I have angular 12 + node 14 project. Can someone please help me? I have gone through all the posts related to this. I get undefined everytime I try to use environment variable.

I've placed `.env` file in the folder where I have my login.component.ts as in my root folder I don't have any ts file from where I could add `require('dotenv').config()`.

In my login.component.ts I added:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: 'C:/Users/.../git/../src/app/authentication/login/.env'});
```

My `.env` file as content like this `CLIENT_ID=sample`.

I have below in my `package.json`

```
"dotenv": "^10.0.0",
"os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
"path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
"process": "^0.11.10",
"webpack": "^5.60.0",
"dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.3"
```

I added all for which I was getting errors. I am trying to build and run using `ng build` and `ng serve`.

Whenever I try this in my `login.component.ts` I get: `undefined` on:

```
console.log('value is ', process.env.CLIENT_ID);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: please use angular environment file for config, there are two built in file name environment one is  used for local (environment.ts) config and 2nd one is for production config (environment.prod.ts), try to use this files.

Comment: I just used a JSON file - https://dev.to/jdgamble555/sharing-secret-environment-variables-with-google-cloud-build-and-angular-universal-7e3

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a `frontend` framework, meaning that things like 'require' or accessing the filesystem just doesn't exists in its scope. Also process isn't a thing in Angular. Just imagine if a website or a webapp could access your filesystem without you to even know it. if you want to declare frontend variables in a `.env` like way just create a JSON file and write something like:

```json
{
 "VAR1": "VALUE",
 "VAR2": "VALUE"
}
```

and then import the json in your code(dynamic imports are a great way of doing that).
If you're building a web-app tho i would recommend you to build a node server that has access to the fs and make requests from angular(through the built-in httpclient) to your server and send back data from there

Comment: Thanks for your response. My requirement is to use a file that I can add to gitignore and will be used only for local development purpose. I created .env for that purpose which has my client id an secret. Not sure if Dynamic json import will work in my case. Also, you mean I can't use the dotenv in my scenario since I am using angular?

Comment: "My requirement is to use a file that I can add to gitignore and will be used only for local development purpose" => Create a file called "env.conf.json" where you write your 'environment' variables, In the .gitignore simply add a new line with "env.conf.json" and git will ignore that file.

"Also, you mean I can't use the dotenv in my scenario since I am using angular?" => You can use it but on the nodejs(server) side since it has access to the filesystem

I'm not sure if it's impossible to read a .env file on frontend but even if it was possible it should be avoided